# How to scroll up and down line by line in a textarea using up and down buttons with React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have a textarea and two buttons (up and down).

How can I scroll up and down line by line in the textarea using the up and down buttons with React.js.

Something like as if I'm writing a note and I move the text cursor up and down the paragraphs using the up and down keys on my keyboard.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eEXU.png

Simplified code:

```
    import React from "react";
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div>
          <button>Up</button>
          <br />
          <textarea placeholder="YOUR NOTES" />
          <br />
          <button>Down</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me out. I thought I should come back here and share the solution with everyone else who might need it in the future.

```
import React from "react";

const goUp = (id) => {
  var maxScrollTop = id.scrollHeight - id.clientHeight;
  if (id.scrollTop !== 0) {
    id.scrollTo({
      top: id.scrollTop - 10,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }
};
const goDown = (id) => {
  var maxScrollDown = id.scrollHeight - id.clientHeight;
  id.scrollTo({
    top: id.scrollTop + 10,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const okay = document.getElementById("text");
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => goUp(okay)}>Up</button>
      <br />
      <textarea id="text" placeholder="YOUR NOTES" />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => goDown(okay)}>Down</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I will recommend to pass function like that.

import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={goUp}>Up</button>
      <br />
      <textarea id="notes"  placeholder="YOUR NOTES" />
      <br />
      <button onClick={goDown}>Down</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const goUp = () => {
  
  const id = document.getElementById("notes");
  var maxScrollTop = id.scrollHeight - id.clientHeight;
  if (id.scrollTop !== 0) {
    id.scrollTo({
      top: id.scrollTop - 10,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }
};
const goDown = () => {
  const id = document.getElementById("notes");

  var maxScrollDown = id.scrollHeight - id.clientHeight;
  id.scrollTo({
    top: id.scrollTop + 10,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
};
```